# Porque la promesa me retorna undefined, cuando uso console.log

Tags: api, undefined

consulta, estoy creando mi primer modulo, quiero obtener la lista de pokemones para el paginador, pero me retorna undefined en el console.log, donde estaria el error ?

```
export function obtenerListaPokemones (limit = 6, offset = 0) {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`)
       .then((respuesta) => respuesta.json())
       .then((respuesta) => { return respuesta })
}

import { obtenerListaPokemones } from './api/solicitudes.js'

console.log((obtenerListaPokemones(12, 6)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay error, la función ***obtenerListaPokemones()*** no devuelve nada, el **return** que usas del segundo **then** no define el valor devuelto por la función ***obtenerListaPokemones()***, sino el valor devuelto por la función donde se llama al **return** (la función de devolución de llamada del segundo then).

Además, en caso de que la función devolviese los Pokemones, el **console.log()** no esperaría a que los datos llegaran de la API para imprimir el resultado.

En resumen, podrías hacer que la función devolviese una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises):

```
export function obtenerListaPokemones(limit = 6, offset = 0) {
  return new Promise((resolver, rechazar) => { 
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`)
    .then((respuesta) => respuesta.json())
    .then((respuesta) => resolver(respuesta)) // si todo sale bien, la promesa se resuelve con los datos de los pokemones
    .catch(err => rechazar(err)) // caso contrario, se resuelve con el error
  })
}
```

Y ahora si podrias imprimir sin problemas:

```
obtenerListaPokemones()
  .then(pokemones => console.log(pokemones))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Aun mas facil con await:

```
console.log(await obtenerListaPokemones())
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder!
En el caso de que quisiera que la funcion retorne algo, donde deberia ubicar el return y de que manera ? Gracias

Comment: @LucasNouetGuilenia deberías asegurarte de que el return se encuentre directamente dentro de la función *obtenerListaPokemones* y no dentro de otra función mas. Eso con código síncrono. El caso con código asíncrono (que involucra tareas de duración indefinida, como la llamada a una api como la de los pokemones) es diferente y por eso se usan promesas. Puedes notar la diferencia entre sincronia y asincronia [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing)

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!!!!